# Elastic Beanstalk Docker images failing to pull

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am upgrading one of our EB environments and using `python:3.6.1-alpine` as a new Docker image. The problem is Elastic Beanstalk is failing to find the docker image tag for `3.6.1-alpine`

```
Pulling repository docker.io/library/python
Tag 3.6.1-alpine not found in repository docker.io/library/python. Check snapshot logs for detail
```

Pulling the image locally does work however:

```
(env)lappy:project dave$ docker pull python:3.6.1-alpine
3.6.1-alpine: Pulling from library/python
709515475419: Already exists
7f8ede2d2484: Already exists
3f793c092168: Pull complete
a2a8b8745877: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:6ebe18fd00f5175b5f1fe45bfb131f22f5d997f4fe361546cf0a13de396b8009
Status: Downloaded newer image for python:3.6.1-alpine
```

I'm not really sure what's going on because this is an existing Application in Beanstalk that has been online for almost a year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution to the problem. I rebuilt my Elastic Beanstalk Environment and I am able to `sudo docker pull python:3.6-alpine` on the instance. I do not know the cause of this issue or why it suddenly works when rebuilding but this does fix the issue.